# Cannot get fancybox2 to show

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

If someone could look at my source code and tell me why fancybox is not working I would be very grateful. I have commented out all other `js` or `jquery` needs of the page in development so the site menu may not work but I can not figure out why the default fancybox will still not run:

[www.ascent-sation.co.uk.gridhosted.co.uk/wedding-flowers.php](http://www.ascent-sation.co.uk.gridhosted.co.uk/wedding-flowers.php)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".fancybox")` isn't selecting anything. This should do the trick:

```
$(".fancybox-buttons").fancybox();
```

Generally a good idea to diagnose an issue like this is to play on JSFiddle and try and get it working. If you can get it working on a fresh start and not on your site then it's either a typo or an interaction problem. Also stepping through line by line and playing in the console is effective. Running `$(".fancybox")` returned `[]`.

Comment: Thanks very much guys,i left the more sophisticated class in place when at my wits end not being able to get the buttons version to work, so I replaced the script code with the basic one and forgot the class. However, I still could not get the buttons working this morning on my site or jsfiddle(thanks for the tip), despite just copy and pasting the code from the fancy box example.  After a couple of deletions and re pasting it worked  -and I still do not know why!!!